# Align an element to the bottom

Tags: html, css, alignment, vertical-alignment

I need to align an element to the bottom. This is the code:

```
$products_name = '<table border="0" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="0">' .
                   '  <tr>' .
                   '    <td class="productListing-data" ><a href="' . tep_href_link(FILENAME_PRODUCT_INFO, 'products_id=' . $products[$i]['id']) . '"><img hspace=5 src=' . DIR_WS_IMAGES . 'images_90xh/'. $products[$i]['image']. ' alt="' . $products[$i]['name'] . '" border="0" width="90" class="find_image_height"></a><br></td>' .
                   '    <td style="font:10pt tahoma;" ><a href="' . tep_href_link(FILENAME_PRODUCT_INFO, 'products_id=' . $products[$i]['id']) . '"><b>' . $products[$i]['name'] . '</b></a>';
  $products_name .= '<br><font style="font:8pt tahoma;color:#666666">В наличии. Дата отправки: <b>'.$wdays2[date('N', $maxdate)-1].' ('.date('d-m-Y', $maxdate).')</b></font><br>'.tep_draw_checkbox_field('cart_delete[]', $products[$i]['id'],false,'class="hide_check_box" key="'.$key.'"').'<span class="delProductbutton del_text" style="vertical-align:bottom;">Delete</span>';
```

$products_name .= '    ';

I need to align to the bottom .del_text (Delete)

Thank you!

Comment: Can you create a Fiddle please?

Answer (score 0):

Not a pretty solution but you may try the html attribute `valign="bottom"`

Comment: yes, I tried, but it worked only for div with position:relative